# How to convert actionscript code into c code?

Tags: c, actionscript

Can anybody suggest how to convert actionscript to c code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic way of doing that. The languages offer very different sets of features.

You'll have to do it manually, preferably in a top-down manner. This means that when making the C implementation, write the most abstract functionality first, gradually going into the details.